# How to execute sql script in pentaho and store in xml.

Tags: pentaho-cde, pentaho-spoon

I have a requirement where I need to run a sql script containing multiple select statement and then to store in a xml file using pentaho.  I need to do this using  command line as a cron job will initiate the execution of sql script. I tried using execute sql script but no success.  Can any one please suggest me how to do it using pentaho or any other better etl tool which is open source.  Thanks

Comment: What do you need to store in an XML file? Output of those queries? Do you want to store result of a different query in a separate file? Please also provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - sample query with expected output from DB and a XML file storing these results (structure).

Comment: Hi Kamil yes i need to store output of those queries but in a single xml file.  Queries are simple like selest * from tablename